# How to set application insights TelemetryClient timeout?

Tags: azure-application-insights

I am sending application insights metric event from a client app (.net) and I am wondering if I can set a timeout for the TelemetryClient.Flush() since this is a synchronous call. (The app will exit when the operation is done so I need to enforce a flush call to ensure the metric got sent).

Comment: 1. Flush is not synchronous. Internally it starts a task to send data accumulated in the buffer 2. Could you please elaborate more what do you want to achieve? Why do you need a timer?

Comment: I was reading this https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-custom-events-metrics-api/#flushing-data which says the flush is a synchronous call. My app will exit immediately after main operation finish and I don't want the flush call to impact the operation duration.

Answer (score 1):

Flush method implementation depends on the channel that you use.

If you use WebTelemetryChannel which is default for web SDK (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.TelemetryChannel/) than Flush is async.

If you use PersistenceChannel which is default for devices SDK (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PersistenceChannel/) than Flush is sync. As Izik mentioned no overrides are available.

Comment: I think the one I am seeing is InMemoryChannel, do you know the behavior of this one?

Answer (score 0):

Flush is a blocking operation and it doesn't support any timeout out of the box, but you can always start a new task, run Flush in it and [wait (with timeout)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235606(v=vs.110).aspx) for this task to end.

As a side note, Flush doesn't send any telemetries it just persists to disk, so it is relatively fast.